# From where ls gets inode info in a deleted directory

Tags: linux, bash, ls, inode

I am not able to understand `ls` and `cd` behaviour in following case :
Create directory `a/b/c`

```
$ mkdir a/b/c -p
$ ls -lhRai
.:
total 324K
24512531 drwxrwxr-x  3 mayank mayank 312K May 22 16:23 .
24380771 drwxr-xr-x 34 mayank mayank 4.0K May 22 15:14 ..
25690305 drwxrwxr-x  3 mayank mayank 4.0K May 22 16:23 a

./a:
total 324K
25690305 drwxrwxr-x 3 mayank mayank 4.0K May 22 16:23 .
24512531 drwxrwxr-x 3 mayank mayank 312K May 22 16:23 ..
25690306 drwxrwxr-x 3 mayank mayank 4.0K May 22 16:23 b

./a/b:
total 12K
25690306 drwxrwxr-x 3 mayank mayank 4.0K May 22 16:23 .
25690305 drwxrwxr-x 3 mayank mayank 4.0K May 22 16:23 ..
25690307 drwxrwxr-x 2 mayank mayank 4.0K May 22 16:23 c

./a/b/c:
total 8.0K
25690307 drwxrwxr-x 2 mayank mayank 4.0K May 22 16:23 .
25690306 drwxrwxr-x 3 mayank mayank 4.0K May 22 16:23 ..
```

`cd` to innermost directory `c`

```
$ cd a/b/c
```

from another terminal, remove directory `a`, i.e.

```
$ rm -rf a
```

but `ls` is still getting **inode** info

```
$ pwd
/home/mayank/Tmp/a/b/c
$ ls -lai .
total 0
$ ls -laid .
25690307 drwxrwxr-x 0 mayank mayank 0 May 22 16:23 .
$ ls -laid 
25690307 drwxrwxr-x 0 mayank mayank 0 May 22 16:23 .
$ ls -laid ../
25690306 drwxrwxr-x 0 mayank mayank 0 May 22 16:24 ../
$ ls -laid ../..
25690305 drwxrwxr-x 0 mayank mayank 0 May 22 16:24 ../..
$ ls -laid ../../..
24512531 drwxrwxr-x 2 mayank mayank 319488 May 22 16:24 ../../..
```

offcourse `cwd` file in `/proc` of bash is pointing to deleted dir

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/cwd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mayank mayank 0 May 22 16:32 /proc/13125/cwd -> /home/mayank/Tmp/a/b/c (deleted)
```

Also, not able to understand `cd` behaviour

```
$ cd ..
cd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory    
$ ls -li
total 0
$ ls -lid
25690306 drwxrwxr-x 0 mayank mayank 0 May 22 16:24 .
$ pwd
/home/mayank/Tmp/a/b/c/..
$ cd ..
cd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
$ pwd
/home/mayank/Tmp/a/b/c/../..
$ ls -lhid
25690305 drwxrwxr-x 0 mayank mayank 0 May 22 16:24 .
$ cd ..    
Tmp:$ ls -lhtrai
total 320K
24380771 drwxr-xr-x 34 mayank mayank 4.0K May 22 15:14 ..
24512531 drwxrwxr-x  2 mayank mayank 312K May 22 16:24 .
Tmp:$ cd -
bash: cd: /home/mayank/Tmp/a/b/c/../..: No such file or directory
```

`cd` was not able to get parent dir info in `c` `b` , but `a`

Comment: The shell is holding the directory open.